# BFS Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I have tried to implement the BFS algorithm with an adjasency table which is implemented with an array of vectors. I start storing input from 1 and not from 0.

EDIT: I have updated the code: http://ideone.com/GZwPP and now it compiles and runs but when I try to search for a node which is not in the graph I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted
```

Comment: The error looks like a problem in your build environment.  It's missing symbols that should be provided by the compiler's utility library for supporting exceptions.

Comment: I can confirm, code works fine for me

Comment: The code compiles - http://ideone.com/dT2fD ignore the runtime error.

Comment: @GeorgeStamatiou What line triggers the `out_of_range` exception? Do you have the call stack? Did you try to debug that?

Comment: I have tried to backtrace in GDP but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is really subtle. You have in your code:

```
for(i = 1; i <= adj[front].size() - 1 && adj[front].at(0) != 0; i++)
```

What type is `size()`? It is an unsigned type. So when `size() == 0` then `size() - 1 > 0` because of [arithmetic overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow). You should change the line to:

```
for(i = 1; i < adj[front].size() && adj[front].at(0) != 0; i++)
```